# Creating hyperlinks to PDF files in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I am trying to create an Excel 'contents sheet', which in theory should have multiple links (done by python script), to multiple PDF's on my work network.

When I enter the following formula into cell A1:

```
=HYPERLINK("\\cd3\Live Data\1047656001 - Cleardata - Digital Services Scripts\Dylan Logan\+Live\[BUREAU] 1195601001 - Jaguar Land Rover - HTML Contents Page\Test.pdf", "Test Hyperlink")
```

Adobe acrobat opens and closes instantly, but when I enter the actual file link into windows explorer it opens fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: tried using other pdf viewer? does it behave similarly?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I have tried using irfanview to do this too, same result :/

Comment: just a suggestion (since I didn't have adobe acrobat to test this..) . You may try to add a [command switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619158/adobe-reader-command-line-reference) to the link.